# React authentication using redux

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

I am creating a user authentication page using react and redux. I submit the login form and then I navigate to the profile page which shows some data of the user. The thing is when I post the data to the server and I get the token in the response, I keep it in the local storage so that I can later fetch the data of this user using that token. I just wonder if there is some way else through which I can store that token in redux, not in the local storage, and pass it to the function that fetches the user data in redux. Here is the action that I use to post the email and the password and store it in the localstorage.

```
function login(email, password) {



    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({ email }));

        userService.login(email, password)
            .then(
                user => {

                      //  console.log(user);
                //      console.log(user.data.token)
                  userService.fetchUserData(user.data.token)
                      .then(response =>{
                          console.log(response.data);
                          dispatch(success(response.data));
                          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));




                          history.push(`${baseURL}/main`);

                      });
                    //history.push('/main');
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));


                }
            );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

And this is the function that fetches the data using the token in the localstorage :

```
function login(email, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
    };

    return fetch(`<backendURL>/auth/login`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
           // localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
           // console.log('this is the token:'+user.data.token);
            let token=user.data.token
     //   console.log('this is the user token:'+token);



            return user;
        });
}
```

I hope that my question is clear enough and I thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to store the User's Authentication token in Redux store.

It is possible to store the Token in the Redux store and get it anytime you want. But you will have to understand that the User session needs to be persisted by the Application on the browser till its valid. And the validity of the session is confirmed by the Server using the Authentication token.

With that being said, The Redux store is cleared on a browser refresh. Meaning all the state stored in the store is lost and the application will be mounted again. This will in turn dispatch all actions and fetch the latest data from the server. To fetch the data from server, the Auth token is required and it will not be available if its stored in the Redux store. That is why you store the Token in localStorage which will ensure that the token is available even if the page is refreshed.

Hope this helps !